# Protractor Failed: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: angularjs, selenium, automation, protractor, webdriver

I am new to Protractor and wiritng an AngularJS protractor test. I am trying to read a Url from Google Chrome console but getting an error "Failed: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined". My code is :

```
let address;
.
.
function readingUrl() {
    browserA.manage().logs().get('browser')
        .then(function (browserLog) {
            var i = 0;
            for (i; i <= browserLog.length - 1; i++) {
                if (browserLog[i].message.indexOf('My Url:') != -1) {
                    address = browserLog[i].message.split('My Url:')[1].toString();
                    return address;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I am calling this function like this:

```
browserB.get(readingUrl()).then(() => {
        browserB.sleep(3000);
    });
```

The url in the Chrome console looks like this:

```
My Url:https://www.google.com/
```

Can someone help me, I am trying to do this and stuck here like forever

Comment: Your `readingUrl` function is not returning anything. The `return address` is returning the address to the arrow function  in the .then. You need to add a return to the first line in order to return anything from this function. You will also need to await for readingUrl to return it's value once called I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try below function:
Instead of returning from "then block" return from readingUrl main function.

```js
let address;
.
.
function readingUrl() {
    browserA.manage().logs().get('browser')
        .then(function (browserLog) {
            var i = 0;
            for (i; i <= browserLog.length - 1; i++) {
                if (browserLog[i].message.indexOf('My Url:') != -1) {
                    address = browserLog[i].message.split('My Url:')[1].toString();
                }
            }
        });
   return address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
readingUrl().then(url => 
  browserB.get(url)
    .then(() => browserB.sleep(3000))
)
```

Comment: can you explain your answer, how it will fix ?

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem but it is always [better to describe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) how it is solving the problem :)

Comment: I don't understand why comments are being removed, but as I said, IF this solves the problem, I WILL explain the solution. Otherwise it's a shot in the dark, because the real problem can be anywhere in the framework